# What this issue displayed in my UV a symptom of?

Tags: mesh, uv, baking

I don't know what the term is for what is displayed, and therefore I can not search for the issue. It's messing up my bakes.  I'm hunting my mesh for the issue and ican't seem to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: I thought maybe I needed to remove doubles, or delete loose,then unwrap again, no effect.

Comment: Probably some geometry you added or modified after unwrapping.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like new geometry added after your intial unwrapping was already done.

Comment: Yeah no new geometry I moved the uv problem uvs out of the path of the main uv structure, and it's no longer blocking my bake, but it doesn't really solve the entire problem. I tried selecting "by trait" to find my problem, that didn't work either